# 'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, express

I'm creating a Node.js application using Express. Normally, to run the application locally, I type in `node app.js`, and everything works fine. However, now I'm using a book to learn how to create express apps, and it asked me to create a bin/www file that has the following in it:

```
#!/usr/bin/nodejs
var debug = require('debug')('my-application');
var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

The book also asked me to install nodemon to run the application. However, everytime I use `npm start` or `nodemon` to start the application, I get the error:

> 'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command

The Environment variables are correctly set, I've double checked.

Here is the debug log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@2.15.8
3 info using node@v4.4.7
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart application-name@0.0.1
6 info start application-name@0.0.1
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info application-name@0.0.1 Failed to exec start script
9 verbose stack Error: application-name@0.0.1 start: `nodejs ./bin/www`
9 verbose stack Exit status 1
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:217:16)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
10 verbose pkgid application-name@0.0.1
11 verbose cwd C:\Users\Humad\Dropbox\projects\loc8r
12 error Windows_NT 10.0.14393
13 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
14 error node v4.4.7
15 error npm  v2.15.8
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error application-name@0.0.1 start: `nodejs ./bin/www`
17 error Exit status 1
18 error Failed at the application-name@0.0.1 start script 'nodejs ./bin/www'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the application-name package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     nodejs ./bin/www
18 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
18 error     npm bugs application-name
18 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
18 error
18 error     npm owner ls application-name
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Change your `start` command to use `node`, not `nodejs`.

Answer (score 2):

As you seem to already know (by typing `node app.js`), the Node process on Windows is `node`, not `nodejs`.

Change your `start` command in package.json to the right command.